# How to give access to virtual machine using remote desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to give access to a friend to use a virtual machine that I created. I am running it in server 2008 R2. I created a profile for him. I gave him a log on name and a password.
I wanted him to be able to use remote desktop to access the profile that was created specifically for him.

I test it and it works, but I figure that's because I'm on the network and that is why it is allowing me to access it. When he tried to remote in, it won't allow him to log in. What did I do wrong?
What else do I need to give him in order for him to have access to it.

Can you walk me through how to setup the access to the virtual machine. I hope I am making sense. 
I am by no means a proficient user.

Comment: When you say "will not allow him to log in", what specifically happens? Does he get some kind of error?

Answer (score 1):

Does the Virtual Machine have an IP address that is accessible from outside of your network? Otherwise known as a Public IP? To find out what it is, you could try (within the virtual server) browsing http://www.whatismyip.com/ 

However, that may not be accessible outside due to your internet. Without getting too technical, you could try a program such as Teamviewer or even Remote Access for Chrome - which are simple solutions.

Alternatively, if you have an IP that is always the same (known as Static) you may be able to configure your Modem (DSL/CABLE) to allow access from the Internet (the programs above, do this automatically)

Let me know which one you want help with!

Comment: Thanks. I got it figured out what i was doing wrong.All is well and i do appreciate you getting back to me